# jQuery - unable to apply CSS animation during CSS class swap

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have two `div`s, which move `30px` up when the user clicks on a `button` (and the other one moves `30px` down). I'm achieving this by swapping between two `css` classes, `up` and `down`. The problem is that I cant add animation to the class swap even when I add `transition: all 1s ease;` to the appropriate `css` class. How can I swap between the two so the `div`s will slide up and down nicely?
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n5vafpw0/2/).

HTML:

```
<div class="row centered plan-container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 plan-col">
        <div class="smallBox">
             <h3>DEMO 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="bigBox">
            <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 plan-col">
        <div class="smallBox">
             <h3>DEMO 2</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="bigBox">
            <button>SELECT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".bigBox button").click(function () {
    var buttonsArray = $(".bigBox button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++) {
        $(buttonsArray[i]).css("background-color", "#1c1d20");
    }
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

    $(this).css("background-color", "#2eb5aa");


    var parents = $(".plan-col");
    for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        $(parents[i]).removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    }


    $(parent).addClass("up");
});
```

CSS:

```
.plan-container {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1000px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50px;
}

.smallBox {
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #2e2f3c;
}
.bigBox {
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #2e2f3c;
}

.bigBox button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 10px 55px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #2eb5aa;
    background-color: #1c1d20;
    color: white;
    outline:0;
}
.up {
    bottom:30px;
}
.down {
    up:30px;
}
.col-plan {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: CSS has no `up` property as far as I know. In addition, transition between `bottom: 30px` and `top: 30px` (different properties) won't work in most browsers (or atleast they didn't till sometime back). Try something like `bottom: calc(100% - 30px)` for the `.down`.

Comment: `up` is just a class I created, I need this `class` to apply + an animation

Comment: using slideup and down is more simple.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slideup_slidedown

Comment: The opposite of `bottom` is `top` not `up`

Comment: @undroid You are trying to use a property `up` in your CSS, there isn't. BTW, there is no element with class `col-plan` in provided HTML markup

Comment: I updated, forgot to add the `col-plan` to the element that needs to be animated. `up` is there, btw.

Comment: @undroid: Either I am completely lost (or) you are. You are saying `.col-plan` should be animated but the class change seems to be happening for `.plan-col` and that doesn't have any transition setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good sleep I came up with the right solution I was looking for. For those who are interested, here is the `js` code that handles the animation:

```
var parents = $(".selected");
for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
    $(parents[i]).animate({
    'marginTop' : "+0px" //moves down
    },{queue: false});
    $(parents[i]).removeClass("selected");
}

var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
$(parent).addClass("selected");

$(parent).animate({
    'marginTop' : "-30px" //moves up
    },{queue: false});
```

Fully functioning example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n5vafpw0/9/).

Answer (score 1):

I made quite a few changes to your code as I tinkered a little bit, I'm afraid. But it works!

AFAIK, CSS3 Transitions only occur on an event, so you can't really do what you were trying to do (animate the styles of `.col-plan` from a different element, the`<button>`). So this uses jQuery to animate, which kind of deviates from your original intent to use CSS transitions. Sorry =(.

---

Here's what I changed:

- the **jQuery**. Notice instead of changing classes, I used jQuery's `animate()`. The CSS transition does handle the timing, though, so you don't have to put in a length in ms. I also switched out the `for` loop for a jQuery `each()` function and removed extra `$( ... )`s.

  ```
     $(".bigBox button").click(function () {
      var buttonsArray = $(".bigBox button");
      for (var i = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++) {
          $(buttonsArray[i]).css("background-color", "#1c1d20");
      }
      var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
      $(this).css("background-color", "#2eb5aa");

      var parents = $(".col-plan");
      parents.each(function() {
          $(this).animate({"top": "0"});
      });

      parent.animate({"top": "auto", "bottom": "30px"});
  });
  ```
- the **CSS**:

  - `.plan-col` should be `.col-plan`. You have no `.plan-col` class in your code.
  - I removed the `.up` and `.down` classes, because they are only one style, and you can do that with jQuery. Also, as in the comments above, `up` should be `top`.

---

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/n5vafpw0/6/) on JSFiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesnt quite do what I'm trying to achieve. It only animates for the first `click`, and then not being animated anymore afterwards, and there is no animation to the downwards part. What do you think? something like here: http://jsfiddle.net/n5vafpw0/7/